# Spring Rabbit MQ Publish and Acknowledge

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rabbit

In my project i am having 3 Classes App(**Publisher**), PojoListener(**Receiver**) , Config(**bind both App and PojoListner**). But i need to separate out the PojoListener from my project and deploy somewhere else so that my Listener class will continuous listen to the Rabbit Mq and ack the messages back to queue and then to App Class for any messages published by my App class.

As my config file is common for both Publisher and Receiver. Is there any way to seperate out them. I need to deploy my receiver on different server and Publisher on different. Both will listen to common queues.

```
**App.java** :
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {        
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(RabbitMQConfig.class);
        RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class);
        String response = (String) rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("message from publisher");
        System.out.println("message sent");
        System.out.println("response from :" + response);
    }
}
```

**PojoListener.java :**

```
public class PojoListener {

    public String handleMessage(String msg) {
        System.out.println("IN POJO RECEIVER!!!");
        return msg.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

**RabbitMQConfig.java** :

```
@Configuration

public class RabbitMQConfig {

@Bean

public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {

    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
    connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");
    return connectionFactory;
}  


@Bean

public RabbitTemplate fixedReplyQRabbitTemplate() {

    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    template.setExchange(ex().getName());
    template.setRoutingKey("test");
    template.setReplyQueue(replyQueue());
    template.setReplyTimeout(60000);
    return template;
}


@Bean

public SimpleMessageListenerContainer replyListenerContainer() {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(replyQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(fixedReplyQRabbitTemplate());
    return container;
}



@Bean

public SimpleMessageListenerContainer serviceListenerContainer() {

    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(rabbitConnectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(requestQueue());
    container.setMessageListener(new MessageListenerAdapter(new PojoListener()));
    return container;
}


@Bean

public DirectExchange ex() {

    return new DirectExchange("rabbit-exchange", false, true);
}

@Bean

public Binding binding() {

    return BindingBuilder.bind(requestQueue()).to(ex()).with("test");
}


@Bean

public Queue requestQueue() {

    return new Queue("request-queue-spring");
}


@Bean

public Queue replyQueue() {

    return new Queue("response-queue-spring");
}

@Bean

public RabbitAdmin admin() {

   return new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory());
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean - you can simply split the config into 3 files - common, producer, and consumer-related Beans.

Comment: Do you have any sample project for the illustration. It will be very helpful.